# Are consensus protocols in hyperledger pluggable? Can we use Indy's RBFT(Plenum) in Fabric network somehow?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, consensus

I'm using Hyperledger Fabric and for consensus I want to use RBFT.I checked the other hyperledger fabric projects and saw Hyperledger has an implementation of RBFT as plenum .Can I use it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Consensus Algorithms in Hyperledger Sawtooth have always been pluggable. Originally there was PoET, which is a lottery-style consensus that is much more energy efficient than Bitcoin's PoW. Recently added are voting-class consensus algorithms PBFT and Raft. The choice of consensus algorithms depends on your use case--number of nodes and finality among them.

Someone else can chime in about other Hyperledger platform consensus algorithms, such as Hyperledger Fabric or Hyperledger Indy.

To answer your other question, no consensus algorithms are not portable among the various Hyperledger platforms such as Sawtooth, Fabric, or Indy. That would be an admirable goal, however.